# ReducedPom inside generated jar with maven shade

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I understand that the dependency reduced pom generated by the maven shade plugin is a condensed pom for the uber jar. Furthermore, the location *in* the file system of this pom can determined with `<dependencyReducedPomLocation>`.
However, is it possible to have this new, reduced pom included as `META-INF/pom.xml` *in* the uber jar file to allow to reuse the uber jar with maven for the still existing dependencies?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what problem you're having. When I install an uber jar I get a pom.xml in my local repository and can use the uber jar in other projects. What do you want to do that isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I try generate the uber jar which I want to install in another project as a local jar by means of a local repository. This second project spits out a warning that the first jar does not include a pom.xml